# Как сложить два весовых вектора?

Tags: алгоритм, нейронные-сети

К примеру

0100 + 1010 = 1110

0-100 + 1100 = 1000

а если 
1011 + 1000 = ?

или

-1-100 + -10-11 = ?

Comment: Ниче непонятно - яснее формулируйте вопрос

Comment: Весовой вектор - понятие из алгоритма обучения с исправлением ошибки. 
Там есть момент когда векторы нужно складывать что бы найти новый вектор. Как их правельно складывать? 

Примеры сложения: 

0001 + 000-1 = 0000

1000 + 001-1 = 101-1

1111 + -1-1-10 = 0001 

Если складывать каждое отдельное число то получаем 

1 + -1 = 0

1 + 0 = 1

-1 + 0 = -1

А как складывать такие числа 

1110 + 1101 к примеру, где речь идет о 1 + 1 

Бинарное сложение тут не работает, так как элемент может принимать три значения -1 0 1

Comment: тогда всего лиш пара правил:

    0 + 0 = 0
    0 + 1 = 1
    0 +-1 =-1
    1 + 1 =-1
    1 +-1 = 0
    -1+-1 = 1

Comment: @tamahcki пишет - "элемент может принимать три значения -1 0 1" - @Spectre, Ваши правила надо понимать как таблицу истинности операции OR в троичной системе ? 

Т.е. сложение в троичной системе без переноса ?

Comment: А изначально -- откуда это? Т.е. стартёр топика что-то не дочитал и вопрошает, что же написано на этих недочитанных им страницах? (Есть небольшой наводящий вопрос -- а увидеть хотя бы прочитанные страницы можно?)

Comment: @avp, скорее не OR, а обычное сложение по модулю 3, только все значение уменьшены на единицу и вместо 0,1,2 получаем -1,0,1 с поправкой на отрицательную единицу

Comment: Это из теории нейронных сетей -1, 0, +1 это значения персептрона. Надо сложить выходы всех персептронов, так?

Answer (score 1):

Если это вопрос к программисту, то перевести вектор (это скорее всего строка string) в соответствующий тип (int - со знаком), сложить и перевести в двоичный вид. Если же надо создать алгоритм для любого количества знаков 0-1, то здесь уже задача делится на 2 части: Анализ формулы и разделение на операции, запуск вычисления элементарной части этой формулы как показано в комментарии к вопросу, вывод результата.

Comment: Похоже, человеку нужна таблица сложения для однокомпонентных векторов. Но такая таблица зависит от смысла самих компонент.

Answer (score 0):

А почему нельзя считать, что 1 + 1 = 1 и, соответственно, (-1)+(-1)=-1? Я так понимаю, что при равенстве компонент они "подтверждают" друг друга?
Вы бы объяснили смысл этих векторов, мы бы лучше поняли вопрос!